# specific value php counter

Tags: php, mysql

I used a counter to set the value of an element to a specific number. Is there a way to match the value from the element given by the counter with a database value?

Example:

I have a project with type 2. There are only 3 types (not available in database). Now, I have a selection with those types. And I have set those select values to the counter's value.

This is what I tried so far:

```
<?php

$i = 0;

$selected = '';

if ($i++ == $project->type) {

$selected = 'selected="selected"';

}

?>

<select>
<option value="<?php echo $i++; ?>" <?php echo $selected; ?>>Type 1</option>
<option value="<?php echo $i++; ?>" <?php echo $selected; ?>>Type 2</option>
<option value="<?php echo $i++; ?>" <?php echo $selected; ?>>Type 3</option>
</select>
```

How can I match that counter value with the project type?

I need that to be able to select the selected project type.

Thanks

Comment: You should output the `options` from within a loop or wrap each of them in different `if`s. Currently your `$selected` variable will apply the same state to each option, i.e. either all are selected or otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeroen, $i++ is to increase the value in a **for** loop. You cannot use it like that.
Prefer a DRY method to produce dynamically the types so you can check the selected only one time:

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    $types=array(0=>'select', 1=>'Type 1',2=>'Type 2',3=>'Type 3');
    ?>
    <select>
    <?php foreach($types as $typeID => $typeValue){ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $typeID; ?>" <?php echo ($i == $project->type ? 'selected="selected"' : ""); ?> /><?php echo $typeValue;?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
```

So the $i counter would produce the selected value on your drop down